# What's wrong with this cucumber regex?

Tags: regex, kotlin, cucumber, cucumber-java

I tried to define this custom parameter type:

```kotlin
ParameterType("complex", """(?x)
    | complex\( \s*
    |   (?:
    |     ($realRegex)
    |     (?:
    |       \s* ([+-]) \s* ($realRegex) \s* i
    |     )?
    |   |
    |     ($realRegex) \s* i
    |   )
    | \s* \)
    |""".trimMargin()) {
        realPartString: String?, joiner: String?, imaginaryPartString1: String?, imaginaryPartString2: String? ->

        // handling logic omitted as it doesn't matter yet
}
```

Cucumber is giving an error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$2Adapter.nextInt(Spliterators.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.PrimitiveIterator$OfInt.next(PrimitiveIterator.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.PrimitiveIterator$OfInt.next(PrimitiveIterator.java:86)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.GroupBuilder.build(GroupBuilder.java:18)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.GroupBuilder.build(GroupBuilder.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.GroupBuilder.build(GroupBuilder.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.TreeRegexp.match(TreeRegexp.java:78)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.Argument.build(Argument.java:15)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpression.match(CucumberExpression.java:144)
    at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.StepExpression.match(StepExpression.java:22)
    at io.cucumber.core.stepexpression.ArgumentMatcher.argumentsFrom(ArgumentMatcher.java:30)
```

It sounds as if I have missed a closing group but I've been staring at it for hours and can't see what I've done wrong yet.

I thought maybe throwing it to StackOverflow would immediately get someone to spot the issue. LOL

In case it matters, the definition of `$realRegex` is as follows:

```kotlin
private const val doubleTermRegex = "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"
private const val realTermRegex = "(?:-?(?:√?(?:$doubleTermRegex|π)|∞))"
const val realRegex = "(?:$realTermRegex(?:\\s*\\/\\s*$realTermRegex)?)"
```

That code has been around for much longer and is exercised by many tests, so I'm guessing the issue is in the new code, but I guess you never know.

Versions in use:

- Cucumber-Java8 5.7.0
- Kotlin-JVM 1.5.21
- Java 11

In any case, here's the whole file for context.

```kotlin
package garden.ephemeral.rocket.util

import garden.ephemeral.rocket.util.RealParser.Companion.realFromString
import garden.ephemeral.rocket.util.RealParser.Companion.realRegex
import io.cucumber.java8.En

class ComplexStepDefinitions: En {
    lateinit var z1: Complex
    lateinit var z2: Complex

    init {
        ParameterType("complex", """(?x)
            | complex\( \s*
            |   (?:
            |     ($realRegex)
            |     (?:
            |       \s* ([+-]) \s* ($realRegex) \s* i
            |     )?
            |   |
            |     ($realRegex) \s* i
            |   )
            | \s* \)
            |""".trimMargin()) {
                realPartString: String?,
                joiner: String?,
                imaginaryPartString1: String?,
                imaginaryPartString2: String? ->

            if (realPartString != null) {
                if (imaginaryPartString1 != null) {
                    val imaginarySign = if (joiner == "-") -1.0 else 1.0
                    Complex(realFromString(realPartString), imaginarySign * realFromString(imaginaryPartString1))
                } else {
                    Complex(realFromString(realPartString), 0.0)
                }
            } else if (imaginaryPartString2 != null) {
                Complex(0.0, realFromString(imaginaryPartString2))
            } else {
                throw AssertionError("It shouldn't have matched the regex")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The resulting regex seems to be valid, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qRxcWP/2). There is porbably something else in your code that causes the exception.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the question with the full source of the file.

Comment: Which version of Cucumber is this?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje v5.7.0, will update in the question too. I'm sure the answer is spot-on though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `(?x)` as flag expression to enabled white-space and comments in pattern. Which is probably a good idea given the size of the monster.

When using Cucumber Expressions, Cucumber parses your regex. And [the parser didn't include support for flag expressions](https://github.com/cucumber/common/pull/1069) as you are experiencing now. Updating Cucumber to the latest version should fix that problem. You are welcome.